# Generate a byte sequence with fixed size from a string

Tags: c#

I want to create a byte sequence with a fixed length out of a string which has a variable length. What is the best way to archive this. All bytes should be as different as possible.

#### The code is used for research for myself, nothing productive.

This has been my first approach for the generation of the bytes:

```
static byte[] GenerateBytes(string password, Int32 strength)
{
    Byte[] result = new byte[strength];
    Byte[] pwBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
    Int32 prime = GetLowerPrime(pwBytes.Length);
    
    // Offset count to avoid values
    Int32 count = prime;
    Int32 sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) {
        sum += (result[i] = pwBytes[(count++ % pwBytes.Length)]);
    }
    
    count += prime;
    Int32 pcount = prime;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length * 7; i++) {
        result[(i % result.Length)] ^= (Byte)(pwBytes[(count++ % pwBytes.Length)] ^ ((pcount += pwBytes[(count % pwBytes.Length)]) % 255));
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

And generated some samples with 256 / 128 / 64 generated bytes and counted the unique bytes:

```
Password "Short":                170  103  60
Password "LongerX":              173  101  55
Password "Really Long":          169  100  57
Password "Unbelivable Safe!0§$": 162  101  56
Password "MCV":                  119  113  61
Password "AAA":                  50   51   50
Password "BBB":                  67   67   52
Password "AAAAAA":               48   48   48
```

I tried to change the prime selector a bit this improves the generation with short keys but has partly a impact on long ones. I also tracked some statistics of the bytes. Generated and each byte value is used between 9 and 30 times.

#### What do you think about the results? How can i improve the generation of the bytes?

Comment: I hope you expect to have 2 different strings that will produce the same byte sequence, because your input space is larger than your output space

Comment: If this really is for passwords, don't do this yourself - use a recognised cryptographically-strong hashing algorithm.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an off-the-shelf hashing algorithm?

Comment: If it isn't for passwords, *still* don't do this yourself - use a well-known, already-implemented hash function such as [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).

Comment: -1. You need to improve you requirements. So far `new byte[strength]` satisfy all your criteria... And please define "best" - coolest code, cryto strength, fastest...

Comment: To clarify: This is no homework and i don't want to reinvent the wheel. I call it research for personal interest.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't need the coolest code, i actually want a maximum of different bytes ( As i already said above ).

Comment: You should clearly state your goal - default assumption is you need something for real code (not personal entertainment/education). As result you got "use real hash functions" answers. Also your requirement is "as different as possible, it's not required" - just saying "how to implement hash function for strings" could have been better, but I suspect you've already found plenty of explanations of fast and good ways to compute GetHash for all sorts of object on this site and wanted to ask something else...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You are right, i improved the question a bit and also removed the "it's not required". As i already said ( And now added in the question itself ), its research for myself and i want to implement a hash method from ground up and understand what can i improve and why without reading tons of papers.

Comment: +1 to balance my previous -1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You seems to be reinventing the wheel. If you need to make key from the password, use hashing function, or, the best way - one of the standard password-based key derivation function. Search for PBKDF2.

Comment: As much as there's a chance that you're right that he's trying to make a password key, I would say that it is very presumptuous, and doesn't warrant posting an answer to a question that you don't actually know he's asking.

Comment: Hashing string/using PBKDF will also feet his needs, if he just need bytes "as different as possible"

Comment: @SamIam he wants to generate a fixed-size sequence of bytes from a string. An existing hash algorithm does exactly this -- regardless of whether or not the input was a password.

Comment: As already said in comments it's for personal research because i'm interested in creating one for theoretical purposes.

Comment: You should check how hash functions are built, they should meet your criteria.

Answer (score 2):

well if you really want to roll your own solution that has no real practical use other than theoretical interest, (because this sounds like a homework question) just start off with a one-time pad of random bytes and XOR the pwd with the first few bytes, should give you reasonably high entropy for short pwds.

Comment: Its a pure theoretical interest. ( I made my last homework 10 years ago... :- )